# Redirect all traffic from specific interface to Docker interface and container?

Tags: networking, iptables, docker

I have the following architecture:
[image]

**AP1**, **AP2**, **AP3** and **AP4** are devices which expose their own wireless access points with subnet **192.168.10.0/24** and can't be changed.

**WLAN1**, **WLAN2**, **WLAN3** and **WLAN4** are interfaces of my host, connected each with the corresponding device access point (WLAN1 with AP1 and so on...).

I have four docker containers running on the host, each connected to my host with its own docker bridge interface **DRNET**.

For example the first container is connected to the host with DRNET1, the second container with DRNET2 and so on...

Each AP sends **UDP** data on ports **8889**, **8890** and **11111**.

Is there a way to write a set of **iptables** rules in order to:

- redirect all traffic on specified ports from AP1/WLAN1 to DRNET1?
- redirect all traffic on specified ports from AP2/WLAN2 to DRNET2?
- redirect all traffic on specified ports from AP3/WLAN3 to DRNET3?
- redirect all traffic on specified ports from AP4/WLAN4 to DRNET4?